# Depth Camera Intrinsics for Kinect v2

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm trying to get the camera intrinsics for kinect v2 using C#. I'm pretty new to Visual Studio, C# and Kinect v2 and the lack of a detailed official tutorial is driving me crazy..(if there's any please let me know..)

I know there's a function called GetDepthCameraIntrinsics that returns a calibration data but how do I store that data?(What type does the variable has to be to store the data?)

Answer (score 2):

GetDepthCameraIntrinsics() returns a CameraIntrinsics type. You should write the next code to obtained the data:

```
private CoordinateMapper coordinateMapper = null;
private CameraIntrinsics calibrationData;

coordinateMapper = kinectSensor.CoordinateMapper;
```

and after Open the sensor and wait for approx 2 seconds:

```
calibrationData = coordinateMapper.GetDepthCameraIntrinsics();
```

The CameraIntrinsics is a type that contains different data:
[CameraIntrinsic data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhpL3.png)

I used this tutorial: http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/lab01/index.html and there are samples that comes with the Kinect sdk that are really usefull: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v2.0_1409\Samples\Managed.